# The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Produces for "MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON"

Tags: java, rest, jpa, annotations, jax-rs

I am getting a weird warning (while hovering the red line in eclipse) for this very simple restful service code:
(Eclipse draws a red line under "MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON")

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import com.myCompany.annotation.RestfulServiceAddress;
import com.myCompany.myProject.middleware.api.myService;

@RestfulServiceAddress("/myCompany-middleware")
public class myServiceImpl implements myService {

private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@GET
@Path("/getStuff")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Object> getStuff() {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory
            .createEntityManager();
    try {
        return entityManager.createQuery(
                "Select S from Stuff S", Object.class)
                .getResultList();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}

public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

public void setEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
}
}
```

Also maven builds the jar file without problems. But I get an error from the OSGI container, telling me the jar is failed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`@javax.ws.rs.Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) instead of `javax.enterprise.inject.Produces`

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
// import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
```